# Postgres SSL error

Tags: postgresql, drupal, postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to run a Drupal migration via SSH and drush (a command line shell), copying data from a postgres database to mysql.

It works fine for a while (~5 mins or so), but then I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 SSL [error] SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

The postgres database connection seems to have gone, and I just get errors:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 7 no [error] connection to the server
```

It works fine locally, so I think the problem must be with postgres and running a script over SSH - but googling these errors returns nothing useful. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Could be a timeout. first inspect the log (maybe change ssl_renegotiation_limit)

Comment: Yep, that was exactly the problem - query was taking too long to run, I rewrote it and all's fine now. Thanks very much for the help. Do you want to post your comment as an answer & I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a timeout. first inspect the log (maybe change ssl_renegotiation_limit)

BTW: IIRC, the renegotiation does not take place after a fixed amount of time, but after a certain amount of transmitted characters (2GB?)

Answer (score 1):

You should check both your PostgreSQL and MySQL logs for further potential details. If there's not much in the PostgreSQL log, look at the [log_min_error_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) in postgresql.conf. As you'll find through that link, you can tune it to increase the amount of logging. If there's still not clues in the PostgreSQL log, I would look at other components in your system for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had checked the log and there wasn't anything helpful, but I'll try increasing the logging and see if there's any clues there. Cheers, Ben