# ST_Difference correct syntax

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to run ST_Difference on 3D geometries, I have 2 overlapping cubes, cube1 and cube2.

```
CREATE TABLE cube_diff AS
SELECT ST_Difference(cube1.geom, cube2.geom) AS geom
FROM cube1, cube2
```

3D Intersection works fine:

```
ST_3DIntersection(cube1.geom,cube2.geom) AS geom
```

But ST_Difference complains saying I'm working with Polyhedral surfaces, I used ST_IsSolid, it returns true.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, why don't you use ST_3DDifference() with cubes?

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise the 3d version was different! but now I get: 
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

Comment: It seems you lost a connection due to some timeout. Look what I [found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450069/postgres-ssl-error).

Comment: Thanks, I have a old and slow server (I use it for development), how can I find out what the timeout length is and how can I change it?

Comment: [I guess so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97534/is-there-a-timeout-option-for-remote-access-to-postgresql-database).